# SQL Report Builder linked report collapses parameter options by default

Tags: sql, parameters, selection, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

[image]I'm using Report Builder 3.0 and I have a report that links to another report when clicked on.  When the new report opens the parameter options are collapsed by default.  I'd like them to be expanded by default if possible but I haven't been able to find an option for it.

Comment: Could you add screenshot to your question so that we see what exactly is the issue and what is the desired output you want

Comment: I added a picture.  The top is what it launches as.  I'd like it to be expanded automatically like the bottom image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is something I've struggled with previously. What I've done to resolve it is inject some javascript into the ReportViewer.aspx file which would "click" the bar if it detected it was collapsed by default.

In my version of RS, the element to click is called `ReportViewerControl_ToggleParam`, and you can tell if the bar is hidden by looking at the display value of `ParametersRowReportViewerControl`.

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the only option available.